# How to keep a <hr> in the bottom of element?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that I need to put a `hr` in the end of that.

```css
div {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div> this is a test <hr> </div>
```

As you see in the above fiddle, that `hr` is under the text, but I need to set it in the end of `div` (something like `div{border-bottom: 1px solid}`).

**Note:** I cannot use `margin-top` for `hr`. Because sometimes there is a lot of text into `div` and in that case there will be a blank space between `hr` and text forever. I just want to keep it in the bottom of `div` when there is one or two line of text.

Well, how can I do that?

Comment: What about using bottom border for `div`? as you said.

Comment: @MaihanNijat I mentioned it in the question, But unfortunately I cannot to use that in reality. Because I need to set `12px` `margin-right` to that `hr`, And I can't to set `margin` to the `border`.

Comment: Why you delete your question? The idea of this site is help other not just you.

Comment: Then you mark the question as duplicated, but by deleting the question your delete my answer too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well I'm so sorry, You are completely right ..! I hope you accept my apologize.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use position relative + absolute.

```css
div {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div hr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>this is a test<hr></div>
```

**UPDATE**

The pseudo approach (as commented).

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 20px; /*0 without gap*/
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>this is a test</div>
```

Comment: This is good. But in reality there is  `margin-right :20px` for that `hr` and when I use `width: 100%` it goes out of screen. Is there any alternative except `width: 100%`?

Comment: How about `width: calc(100% - 20px);`? like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jL8dv6n8/)?

Comment: Oh, you can also do `right: 20px;` it's even better, see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kutf9cbe/).

Comment: Well played ..! I don't like `calc`, Because it doesn't work on old-browsers.

Comment: Just saw your comment above, you won't need a `hr` if margin is the only concern, use `:after`, demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wam52pue/).

Comment: WTF .. `:-)` ! every time you send me a new and better approach :-) !!! Thanks for your attention buddy

Comment: I know, can't say it's your bad or mines, maybe ask better next time :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to absolutely position the `hr` to the bottom of the `div`, and make sure the `div` uses relative positioning.

```
div {
position: relative;
}

div hr {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
/* additional style declarations here such as width */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a nested element and move `min-height` to it.

CSS:

```
.example > DIV {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="example">
    <div>this is a test</div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the hr tag use this
This should work better.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
p {
  /*If the border isnt close enough you can also use line height*/
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
   <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`<hr>` tag does not support position fixed you can use absolute and relative.
Together with this, you can achieve similar functionality as `postion:fixed`:

```
.horizontalLine{
        /* position:fixed; */
        position: absolute; 
        position: relative;
        border: none; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
    }
```